# How to display name in legend but not on hover?

Tags: python, plotly, hover, plotly-python

I used the trace name, which shows the names as the legend item and on hover. What should I use to display the name only as the legend but NOT on hover, please? Thanks

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## sample DataFrames
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3],'y':[7,8,9]})

fig = px.scatter(df1, x='A', y='B')
fig.add_scatter(x=df2['x'], y=df2['y'])

fig.update_traces(name='Points', showlegend = True)


fig.show()
```

[image]

The desired result is without the red text Points.

**After advice:**

How to combine that with hovertemplate?

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go

## sample DataFrames
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3],'B':[4,5,6]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,2,3],'y':[7,8,9]})

fig = px.scatter(df1, x='A', y='B')
fig.add_scatter(x=df2['x'], y=df2['y'])

fig.update_traces(
    hovertemplate="<br>".join([
        "<b><i>T</i> (R):</b>            %{x:.3f} ± %{customdata[2]:.3f}",
     ])
    )

fig.update_traces(name='Points', showlegend = True, hoverinfo="x+y")


fig.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`hoverinfo`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-hoverinfo) property :

```
fig.update_traces(name='Points', showlegend = True, hoverinfo="x+y")
```

If you are using [`hovertemplate`](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-hovertemplate), wich overrides `hoverinfo`, then you'll need to empty what they call the "*secondary box*" which can be referenced with the tag `<extra>`

> Anything contained in tag `<extra>` is displayed in the secondary box,
> for example "{fullData.name}". To hide the secondary
> box completely, use an empty tag `<extra></extra>`.

For example :

```
fig.update_traces(
  hovertemplate="[...] %{x:.3f} ± %{customdata[2]:.3f}<extra></extra>"
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much and how to combine that with hoverinfo.

Comment: It depends, `hovertemplate` overrides `hoverinfo`, check out the doc.

Comment: And is it possible to do a trick to get the desired result? Or is to possible to include it into hovertemplate?

Comment: You can get the desired result with `hoverinfo="x+y"`, without `hovertemplate`.

Comment: Yes, it works, but is ti not really possible to set hovertemplate and disappear the text?

Comment: It is possible also using hovertemplate (I did not understand clearly in the first place, I updated the answer). You can also remove the hoverinfo property which is not taken into account when using hovertemplate.