# Plotly - clicking on legend items - how to make an initial setting?

Tags: python-3.x, plotly, legend

When someone clicks on a legend item, it becomes grey, and the data disappears, for instance, [here](https://plotly.com/python/legend/). It is possible to set that an item from a legend will be grey after opening the .HTML output and will appear after clicking of that? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that using the [visible](https://plotly.com/python/reference/#scatter-visible) property on the trace, just set `visible='legendonly'`.

> `visible`
>
> Type: enumerated , one of ( `True | False | "legendonly"` )
> Default: `True`
> Determines whether or not this trace is visible. If "legendonly", the
> trace is not drawn, but can appear as a legend item (provided that the
> legend itself is visible).

A common use case is when one has a lot of traces and wants to show only a few of them initially, eg. with `plotly.express` :

```py
import plotly.express as px

df = px.data.gapminder().query("continent == 'Europe'")

# Nb. This creates one trace per country (color='country'), with each trace `name` 
# inheriting the value of its respective country.
fig = px.line(df, x='year', y='gdpPercap', color='country', symbol="country")

# Arbitrary selection
sel = ['Norway', 'Ireland', 'France', 'Switzerland']

# Disable the traces that are not in the selection
fig.update_traces(selector=lambda t: t.name not in sel, visible='legendonly')

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible this this feature also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588459/how-to-display-name-in-legent-but-not-on-hover ?

Comment: I'm not sure how right now but I think yes it's possible.

Comment: How is it called the text next to hovers?