# Improve Plotly line when there is too much line making it hard to read the graph

Tags: plotly-dash

I have this down and wanted to know if I can have the graph show one line first and then add the other lines because it's messy and you can't really see any of the lines when they first appear.

This is what I have now:

[image]

I want it to look sth like this at the very start:
[image]

This is my code:

```
# Line plot for Hour VS Bicycle Rented
hour_line_plot1 = px.line(
    data_frame=df_bike.groupby(['DayofWeek','Hour']).mean('Count').reset_index(),
    x='Hour', y='Count', color='DayofWeek', markers=True,
    labels={'Hour': 'Time', 'Count': 'Average Bike Used'},
    template="simple_white"
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Plotly - clicking on legend items - how to make an initial setting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67633300/plotly-clicking-on-legend-items-how-to-make-an-initial-setting)

Comment: I edited the answer mentioned above in order to provide the most common use case, explaining a bit how to identify/select specific traces when using px. In _your_ case, just `hour_line_plot1.update_traces(selector=lambda t: t.name != 'Tuesday' visible='legendonly')`.