# Plotly Graph Objects - Show trace lines in the legend but hide them in the chart?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

OK, so I am having issues with the trace names, the legend, and hiding the names from the hover info but keeping them in the legend. I've got the following code:

```
# Create a single plot with all three symbols
    fig = go.Figure()

    # Add traces for each symbol in a single plot
    for symbol in ['QQQ', 'SPY', 'IWM']:
        trace = go.Scatter(
                        x=df['index'],
                        y=df[symbol],
                        mode='lines',
                        customdata = df[['CPI', 'GDP', 'CCI', 'Existing Home Sales', 'Federal Funds Rate', 'Federal Interest Rate', 'Nonfarm Payrolls']],
                        hovertemplate = 'Closing Price: %{y:$}<br>CPI: %{customdata[0]:.2f}\tGDP: %{customdata[1]:.2f}\tCCI: %{customdata[2]:.2f}<br>Federal Interest Rate: %{customdata[5]:.2f}<br>Federal Funds Rate: %{customdata[4]:.2f}<br>Existing Home Sales: %{customdata[3]:.2f}<br>Nonfarm Payrolls: %{customdata[6]:.2f}',
                        name=symbol
                        )
        fig.add_trace(trace)
...

# Update the layout for the single plot
    fig.update_layout(
        xaxis=dict(title='Date'),
        yaxis=dict(title='Value', range=y_range, tickformat=".2f", showticklabels=True),
        showlegend=True,
        legend_title_text='Market Indices',
    hovermode='x',
    title=dict(text='<b>Macro-Economic Stock Movements</b>', y=0.975, x=0.5, xanchor='center', yanchor='top', font=dict(size=18)),
    legend=dict(yanchor='top', y=1, xanchor='left', x=1),
    margin=dict(t=50),  # Adjust the top margin to move the graph up
    height = 750
)
```

I'm trying to remove the trace names / labels from showing up on the chart, but keeping them in the legend. When I use the name = '', it removes it from the chart and the legend, which isn't want I want done. Here is a picture to show it visually:

[image: Plotly Trace Name Headache]

Any idea how I can get this working like I want? I can't imagine it being that difficult or such an odd thing to want that it isn't already in the plotly library :\

PS: Even ChatGPT is no help -.-

Solved: Using the link that @EricLavault recommended, looks like I just needed to add  to the end of the hovertemplate property.

Comment: See [How to display name in legend but not on hover?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67588459/how-to-display-name-in-legent-but-not-on-hover/67637858#67637858). "_If you are using hovertemplate, wich overrides hoverinfo, then you'll need to empty what they call the "secondary box" which can be referenced with the tag <extra>_".